# setting image in NSImageView

Tags: cocoa, swift

I need to subclass a NSImageView. An object of this class is instantiated with IB.
When try to set its image (img), I get nil ! Any help ?
class Custom_ImageView:NSImageView
{
    var img=NSImage()

```
override func awakeFromNib()
{
    self.awakeFromNib()

    img=NSImage(size: self.bounds.size)
    self.image=img
    println(self.image) // "nil"
}
```

}

Comment: Please be make sure that bounds.size width or height not coming as zero.

Comment: I hope you mean super.awakeFromNib()

Answer (score 0):

Of course super.awakeFromNib() !
Surprisingly my code works fine although when I println(self.image), I still get nil, println(image) non-nil ! Perhaps self.image is released soon it is used to display the image.
Anyway it works !
Thank you for the answer